# How To Display External Link Icon from Sprite on Right

Tags: html, css, background, css-sprites

How can I display an external link icon on the right side of the link text from a sprite?

**EDIT**
using :after psudo:

```
a.external:after {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    content:url(../img/icons/ico_sprite.png) no-repeat -985px -3px;
}
```

This loads the sprite after the link but doesn't crop to the needed icon. Any more additional lead will be very helpful....

my HTML:

```
<a class="external_ico" href="">myLink</a>
```

and CSS:

```
a.external_ico {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background: url(../img/icons/ico_sprite.png) no-repeat -985px -3px;
}
```

Displays:

> [>]myLink

But what I am needing is:

> myLink [>]

I have also tried this CSS:

```
a.external_ico {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background: url(../img/icons/ico_sprite.png) center right no-repeat -985px -3px;
}
```

but displays:

> myLink

I have no issues if I don't get the icon from a sprite but I have a lot of icons and would like to grab this one from a sprite as-well. Any help would be appreciated. Thnx.

Comment: Try the `:after` pseudo element: http://jsfiddle.net/sskVR/

Comment: I agree with @Passerby, use :after as he instructed. Although if you wanted to get older browsers (IE6 for example) to respect inline-block then you might want to do a bit of research into that.

Comment: @Passerby C Thanx. This gets the image to the right-side but the whole sprite shows - Doesn't crop the image. see my edit above.

Comment: @Andaero Can you show an JSFiddle that uses your sprite image? Because I have been intentionally using a 30x30 image and cropping (5,5)-(25,25) part as the icon to emulate your need. I even sat a full size image beside to compare.

Answer (score 0):

simply add a padding to the right au the `a` element

```
a.external_ico {
    padding-right: 12px;
    background: url('http://www.placehold.it/12x12') center right no-repeat;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/S2meu/

Comment: This won't work if the image is e.g. 120x120 size and OP is using (60,60)-(72,72) part as the icon (which is very likely what OP is doing, considering the negative position he's using).